# wavemaker 6.4.6 or 6.5 standby widget

Tags: widget, standby, wavemaker

if anyone knows that wavemaker supports dojo standby widget?

Here is a examples od this widget:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/widget/Standby

I would like to a realize "Changing overlay color" example, but I don't know how to make a div element with an "data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.Standby"" or "data-dojo-props="target:'basic3', color:'red'"
I have firebug extension for Chrome, and when I read the divs elements on the form, that any have only ID, class and style.
Also, how to make a buttons with this necessary properties for creating standby effect in wavemaker (button data-dojo-id="b5" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button")?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the busy overlay effect but don't need the standby widget exactly, service variables and live variables now have a 'loading dialog' property. Specify the widget to be covered by a loading dialog while the server call is in flight.

WaveMaker has a wm.Dijit (dijit designer) widget under the 'Dijits' section of the palette. You can easily specify a dojo class, e.g. dojox.widget.Standby, and let WM wrap the dijit for you. It automatically sets up the color, image and other properties for you. One challenge I'd expect with standby is the [limitation noted](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/widget/Standby) that it must have its "parent node rooted as a direct child of document.body, or assign the domNode into the tree before calling startup()."

For that level of control, I would expect you'd need to use [createComponent().](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.5/CustomizeAppsWithJS#HCreatingWidgetsatRuntime28advanced29)

Comment: I solved this problem. I used a "Loading dialog" from Pallete->Dialogs and then as service variable used service which calling some action and widget within this dialog appears